# Delete duplicate data that some columns equal zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL Server table that has col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10.

I want delete the duplicate based on col1, col2, col3.

The row that should be deleted is where col6=0 and col7=0 and col8=0.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: If all rows for a given combination of `co1`, `col1`, `col3` have zero values, then you want to delete all the rows?  If this is not desired, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a deletable CTE here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1 AND col6 = 0 AND col7 = 0 AND col8 = 0;
```

The CTE above identifies "duplicates" according to your definition, which is 2 or more records having the same values for `col1`, `col2`, and `col3`.  Then we delete duplicates meeting the requirements on the other 3 columns.